# Regular Expression to replace variable with variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some string that looks like this:

`var string = popupLink(25, 'Any string')`

I need to use a regular expression to change the number inside (note that this is a string inside of a larger string so I can't simply match and replace the number, it needs to match the full pattern, this is what I have so far:

```
var re = new RegExp(`popupLink\(${replace},\)`, 'g');
var replacement = `popupLink(${formFieldInsert.insertId},)`;
string = string.replace(re, replacement);
```

I can't figure out how to do the wildcard that will maintain the `'Any String'` part inside of the Regular Expression.

Comment: First of all, `\\(` and `\\)` must be used in the template string literal used as a regex pattern. To match up to the `)`, you may use `[^)]*`. What does `replace` hold?

Comment: This solved the problem I don't need to worry about the rest of the string if I can just match the parenthesis directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change the number, just change the number:

```
string = string.replace(/popupLink\(\d+/, "popupLink(" + replacement);
```

Example:

```js
var str = "var string = popupLink(25, 'Any string')";
var replacement = 42;
str = str.replace(/popupLink\(\d+/, "popupLink(" + replacement);
console.log(str);
```

If you really do have to match the full pattern, and "Any String" can literally be **any** string, it's much, much more work because you have to allow for quoted quotes, `)` within quotes, etc. I don't think just a single JavaScript regex can do it, because of the nesting.

If we could assume no `)` within the "Any String", then it's easy; we just look for a span of any character other than `)` after the number:

```
str = str.replace(/(popupLink\()\d+([^)]*\))/, "$1" + replacement + "$2");
```

Example:

```js
var str = "var string = popupLink(25, 'Any string')";
var replacement = 42;
str = str.replace(/(popupLink\()\d+([^)]*\))/, "$1" + replacement + "$2");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a number, you should use `\d`. This will match all numbers.
For any string, you can use lazy searching (`.*?`), this will match any character until the next character is found.

In your replacement, you can use `$1` to use the value of the first group between `(` and `)`, so you don't lose the 'any string' value.

Now, you can simply do the following:

```js
var newNumber = 15;
var newString = "var string = popupLink(25, 'Any string')".replace(/popupLink\(\d+, '(.*?)'\)/, "popupLink(" + newNumber + ", '$1')");
console.log(newString);
```